# PHP. PEAR. Crypt_RSA error

Tags: php, pear

I need to create the keys, rsa signature for my data. Do for example on http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/examples.html eventually see an error:

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in Z:\home\localhost\www\Crypt\RSA.php on line 228

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Deprecated](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deprecate) doesn't mean it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your line 228?  PEAR's Crypt_RSA's line 228 is this:

https://github.com/pear/Crypt_RSA/blob/master/Crypt/RSA.php#L228

That is indeed deprecated.

phpseclib's Crypt_RSA's line 228 has been a comment or a definition for quite a few versions:

- https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/0.3.1/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php#L228
- https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/0.3.0/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php#L228
- https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/0.2.2/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php#L228
- https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/0.2.1/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php#L228

My guess: you're using PEAR's Crypt_RSA and are confusing it for phpseclib's Crypt_RSA.  They are ***not*** the same thing.  PEAR's ***entire*** Crypt_RSA (not just a few lines within it but the entire package) is deprecated per pear.net:

http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_RSA

Answer (score 1):

It's more a warning, not an error. The code does still work. Try changing your error_reporting level to not include `E_DEPRECATED` errors.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all) I had to remove the RSA signature data. Refused Crypt_RSA chose for this purpose http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php

Comment: wise choice. I use the openssl-sign too, but I also double-check it using THIS maintained package/implementation of Crypt_RSA, to make sure the openssl algo is still creating it right and in PKCS1 format - even in newer versions of PHP... : https://packagist.org/packages/phpseclib/phpseclib